# Merged indexes Lucene .NET does not yield same results as directly written index

Tags: .net, lucene.net

I have been trying some approaches to do asynchronous initialization of our Lucene Index.

One of witch was to index our data in smaller batches into separate indexes and then merge those into a bigger index.

The problem is that when the task is fully done, our index doesn't seem to yeild the same kind of results.

Now many specific queries will yield the same amount of results, e.g.
contentType: notification

A All document selector also yields the same results. (*:*)

But if I do a wildcard search, e.g. 'c*' the index that was build from fragmented indexes and then merged yields 0 results but the one written in one big go can yield several hundred thousand results (witch is fair as c* is a rather broad search)...

Is there any thing that needs to be done on merged indexes or is there some differences in the handling of them?... I have tried to run Optimize on them, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing any of the details... I'd say you're using far too big a hammer on this nut :)

I've worked with batch created indexes (100's Millions of docs) and incremental indexes (100K+ updates per day on many millions of docs). Both approaches just used a single IndexWriter on a single index directory.

The trick is to tune the IW MergePolicy appropriately and/or to adjust searcher "latency" by only updating the IndexReader occasionally. This essentially "caches" an IR for a period which improves search speed at the expense of being a little out of date. Tune the period based on expectations.

I can expand on the approach if this is still an issue

Comment: I guess it all depends on the complexity of the documents, if you have fairly simple documents with few fields it might be very different than very complex documents. All i know is that it takes more than 1 hour to index all our documents. We have realized that there is a storage bottleneck here as the same set can be done in 7 minutes on a 250K IOPS - 2GB/s storage. So it might not help building indexes in memory and merging them into the disk, but one would really only know by testing it. It's pointless to test performance though if it does not work.

Comment: if you are creating the index "in bulk" rather than continuous updates, you can use SetRAMBufferSizeMB on the IndexWriter to some large value. This will buffer the docs in memory before flushing to disk. The side effect is the segments are much bigger and merging happens much less frequently. I've seen orders of magnitude improvement as the amount of disk IO is drastically reduced.

Comment: Setting the RAM buffer actually only helped until we hit the flush. As it turns out though it was the SAN that caused the majority of our issues, and it still takes around 10 minutes to index ~250K documents (~750 million fields, its estimated that the average amount of fields for each document is ~3000)... The original question still interests me from a theoretical point of view though, why does the merge approach seem to yield a different result, however I couldn't reproduce the problem for a more simple and raw implementation, so the initial though is that it must be in our wrappers)

Comment: There should be no difference between the two approaches. Internally, an index is always a collection of segments. Optimize just collapses the segments and removes deleted docs. There should be no need for optimize.
Flush to ensure that the buffer (an in-memory segment) is persisted to storage. Open a new IR and you should be good. Whether you index in bulk or over time you'll end up with the same result.
Defining a larger memory buffer means less disk IO when inserting in bulk.
An IR is effectively a snapshot of the index at a point in time. Are you querying against a "stale" one?

Comment: Currently the cause is unknown, the point I was trying to make was that it seems to be clear that it's the framework we build in top of Lucene that has the error, indicated by the fact that I could not reproduce the error if I made a far more simple test directly of Lucene and merging of indexes. A state IR could be a cause, but since the *:* yields same results and we don't do any updates I don't think that was the case. Regardless though I will wait with digging further as we are also looking into upgrading to 4.8 which entered beta recently, so this is on hold for now.